# How do I run my new Perl program built by Module::Starter?

Tags: perl

I built myself a new Perl module using [`Module::Starter`](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aStarter), it has the following source code files in lib/:

```
Foo/Bar.pm
Spam.pm
```

I make two test cases in `t/Bar.t` that test `Foo/Bar.pm`. I ran:

```
perl Makefile.PL && make && make test
```

it shows that my 2 test cases are passed.

Bar.pm defines:

```
package Foo::Bar;
```

Spam.pm uses it in this way:

```
use Foo::Bar qw(fun);
```

Despite that test cases can find Foo::Bar no problem, however when I ran Spam.pm individually by `perl Spam.pm`, it reports that Foo::Bar cannot be found in @INC.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<project root>/lib` is generally not in your include path (your `@INC` setting). `make test` will include it (actually `blib/lib`), but to include it in a standalone program during module development you have to do one of

```
perl -Ilib lib/Spam.pm
PERL5LIB=lib perl lib/Spam.pm
```

Or install it (with `make install`), which will make the files available under a directory that is in your include path.

Answer (score 1):

You never installed it. Do so by running

```
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

The test programs run under a special environment that looks for the module under test in a different place. To use the module in a normal program you should install the module with `make install`.

But a module isn't meant for running directly. You don't say what's in your `Spam.pm` but it is unlikely to do anything useful if you just run it as a program.